# VC++ Application crash doesn't show up

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, crash

I'm encoutering a strange behaviour of an application of mine. A crash condition just closes the application and shows up in the OS Eventviewer but doesn't show up any message box when it occurs, the application just closes.....
It is a VC++ VS2019 application. I tried setting set_terminate or set_unexpected functions but nothing changes. It doesn't executes the function at all when crashing.....
As compiler option I tried /EHs, /EHa and /EHsc as well but nothing changes.....
OS is MS WIN10.
The following is what I did to get it crash:

```
char *A;
memset(A, 0, 1024*1024);
```

Any idea on how to get the popup on crash and how to enabled the error handling to trap the crash condition?
Many many thanks and have a nice day!!!!
Take care,
Marc

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: Many thanks but not really helpful. I read the article in the past but was not helpful to solve my problem. Have a nice day.

Comment: strange... This works for me

Comment: Please add the full main.cpp and vcxproj file